# Shin01 and shin.02 influence on model?

Tags: rigging

Hi I would like to match the vertex group with the correct bone,
in this case I am showing the "DEF-shin.02.L" bone, by default this is the area that I "select" , I do not if is right places...how ever, what portion of edgeflow must this bone get ? to useful animation.

[image]

Comment: If you are referring to a "known" rigging setup (riggify I assume, but it could also be blend rig, or something else ...) it would be better to name it.

Comment: I ve used the Riggify addon  I am asigning vertx group to the shin 01 and shin 02, but I do not feel confortable with the Automatic weith painting , I need to weith painting manually, so what sort of vertex group should I paint for shin 01 and shin 02? paint the image on paint software, paint it and help me :D